# Excel VBA: Output Distinct Values and Subtotals

Tags: vba, excel, distinct-values

I have data of this form:

```
Category      Source      Amount
Dues          FTW         $100
Donations     ODP         $20
Donations     IOI         $33
Dues          MMK         $124
```

There is no sort order. The categories are unknown at compile time. I want a VBA macro to cycle through the range, output a list of distinct values, with the subtotals for each. For the above data, it would look like this:

```
Category      Total Amount
Dues          $224
Donations     $55
```

How can I do this? Also, is there a way to make the macro run every time the table above is updated, or is it necessary for the user to click a button?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to use a built in Excel feature to do this. Looping can take a long time and be problematic if you have a lot of values to loop through.

Something like the following might get you started on creating a pivot table (from http://www.ozgrid.com/News/pivot-tables.htm)

```
Sub MakeTable()
Dim Pt As PivotTable
Dim strField As String

    'Pass heading to a String variable
    strField = Selection.Cells(1, 1).Text

    'Name the list range
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Name = "Items"

    'Create the Pivot Table based off our named list range.
    'TableDestination:="" will force it onto a new sheet
    ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Add(SourceType:=xlDatabase, _
        SourceData:="=Items").CreatePivotTable TableDestination:="", _
            TableName:="ItemList"

    'Set a Pivot Table variable to our new Pivot Table
    Set Pt = ActiveSheet.PivotTables("ItemList")

    'Place the Pivot Table to Start from A3 on the new sheet
    ActiveSheet.PivotTableWizard TableDestination:=Cells(3, 1)

    'Move the list heading to the Row Field
    Pt.AddFields RowFields:=strField
    'Move the list heading to the Data Field
    Pt.PivotFields(strField).Orientation = xlDataField
End Sub
```

This is for subtotals (though I much prefer pivot tables)
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa213577(office.11).aspx

---

EDIT:
I reread and have the following thoughts. Set up the pivot table on a separate sheet (without using any code) then put the following code on the sheet that has the pivot table so that the table will update everytime the sheet is selected.

```
    Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()

    Dim pt As PivotTable

        'change "MiPivot" to the name of your pivot table
        Set pt = ActiveSheet.PivotTables("MyPivot")

        pt.RefreshTable

    End Sub
```

---

Edit #2
Refresh all pivot tables on sheet
http://www.ozgrid.com/VBA/pivot-table-refresh.htm

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()    
    Dim pt As PivotTable

    For Each pt In ActiveSheet.PivotTables
        pt.RefreshTable
    Next pt
End Sub
```

The link has multiple options on how to refresh pivot tables in the sheet/workbook.

Comment: I agree, Pivot Tables is what you are after

Comment: how do I find the name of the pivot table/chart?

Comment: Right click on the pivot table and select pivot table options. That will show you the current name and allow you to change the name if you want.

Comment: and how do I make it so `Worksheet_Activate` is called every time the sheet is selected?

Comment: also, is there a way to make it more general, like "refresh all pivot tables on this sheet?"

Comment: if you place the worksheet_activate code in the sheet you want it to run on, it will be triggered every time the user visits that sheet.

Comment: I've added edit #2 to show refresh all pivot tables on this sheet. and added a link that describes a lot more pivot table refresh options.