# Excel VBA SubTotals

Tags: vba, excel, pivot-table, subtotal

Excel build-in functions are, at most of the time, effective. However, there are some functions really like implemented half-way and some how dictated their usage. The SUBTOTAL function is one of them.

My data is presented in the following format:

```
    Value   Count
    100        20
    102         3
    105         4
    102         5
```

And I want to build a table in this format:

```
    Value   Count
    100        20
    101         0
    102         8
    103         0
    104         0
    105         4
```

I've read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1603414/excel-vba-output-distinct-values-and-subtotals) in SO but my situation is a bit differ. Pivot table will be able to give you the subtotals of the values appears in the original data and I don't want to have a loop to insert missing values in the original data (if it is gonna to be a loop over the original data, the loop could use to build the table - which I would prefer to avoid at all)

Comment: Why not add another sheet and use `SUMIF`?

Comment: Thanks for your comment! I'll need to sort the original data in order to setup the criteria in the SUMIF function. My data set has more than 50,000 rows. I want to explore options other than having VLOOKUP or MATCH functions for each row in the original data.

Comment: You don't need to do this. You can copy your `Value` column to a new sheet, remove duplicates, then sort it, add the `SUMIF` and you are done...